# Google Maps API v3: Setting higher maxzoom than 30 in ImageMapType

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working on a demo for a GPGPU Cluster framework, which dynamically generates Mandelbrot tiles.

I wanted to present it in a Google-Maps-Style. I've never worked with the Google Maps API before, so I'm having some trouble.

I will be using ImageMapType with a custom getTileUrl function that connects to the tile generating server.

I used the following example:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image

The problem I'm having is ... I need 40+ zoom levels, but this config:

```
var moonTypeOptions = {
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
      var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
      return "http://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw" +
          "/" + zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" +
          (bound - coord.y - 1) + ".jpg";
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  maxZoom: 60,
  minZoom: 0,
  name: "Mandelbrot"
};
```

still leaves me with only 30 levels of zoom.

What is the problem?
Why is there a limit to the maxZoom value, and how can you change it?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: Sadly, I didn't... Seems to be a problem with floating point accuracy or something.